# SQL query to find the time difference

Tags: sql

I want to find the time difference between the login and logout of a user.
The hard part for me is that both login and logout time is in one column and there is a "Status" column to show if it is login/logout.
**Example:**

```
Timestamp             Status       UserName

2015-04-26 20:12:33   Login        Grashia

2015-04-26 23:22:13   Logout       Grashia
```

How do I query this?
I tried the DATEDIFF function but I know thats not the right way.

Comment: If that's all you have you're SOL, SQL queries aren't ordered.

Comment: Whats your RDBMs and how do you want to show the result? Hours? Minutes, seconds, Days? What is your table like? How we will know from which user is each time? Lots of gaps in your question

Comment: Username is another column in the table. So consider I have three columns Username Timestamp and Statu. The username will be the same for login and logout. I want the difference in Minutes.

Comment: Will it just contain 2 entries per user (i.e. Login and Logout) or series of entries. It yes, you want the difference between consecutive entires of login and logout?

Comment: it contains only 2 entries. youre right I want consecutive entries for loginand logout.

Comment: DATEDIFF is product specific. Tag dbms used!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `user_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

with this sort of data

```
+----+---------+---------------------+--------+
| id | user_id | dt                  | status |
+----+---------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | 2015-09-23 08:35:36 | Login  |
|  2 |       1 | 2015-09-23 17:15:44 | Logout |
|  3 |       1 | 2015-09-24 08:55:18 | Login  |
|  4 |       2 | 2015-09-23 09:00:16 | Login  |
|  5 |       2 | 2015-09-23 18:00:23 | Logout |
+----+---------+---------------------+--------+
```

You can use this query

```
SELECT i.user_id, i.dt AS 'login_dt', IFNULL(o.dt, '-') AS 'logout_dt',
    TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(o.dt, NOW()), i.dt) AS 'total_time' 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM user_log WHERE `status`='Login') i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM user_log WHERE `status`='Logout') o 
        ON i.user_id=o.user_id AND DATE(i.dt)=DATE(o.dt)
```

to get this result

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id | login_dt            | logout_dt           | total_time |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|       1 | 2015-09-23 08:35:36 | 2015-09-23 17:15:44 | 08:40:08   |
|       1 | 2015-09-24 08:55:18 | -                   | 00:10:23   |
|       2 | 2015-09-23 09:00:16 | 2015-09-23 18:00:23 | 09:00:07   |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

You have to add required indices and set proper table engine for optimum performance

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (Some product specific SQL there, and question has no dbms specified, so ANSI SQL is assumed.)

Answer (score 1):

if it is SQL server your query will look like this:

I suppose that there should be a column userid:

You need to join two table to make compare data in the same column

```
SELECT in. username, DATEDIFF(minute, in.timestamp, out.timestamp)
FROM
(SELECT username, timestamp FROM logtable WHERE status = 'Login') as IN
INNER JOIN
(SELECT username, timestamp FROM logtable WHERE status = 'logout') AS OUT 
ON in.userid =  out.useriD
```

you can read more about DATEDIFF function here:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx